# Why cant I return the index of a value I have searched for in an array?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have code to ask the user to enter a search value, which should then be compared against every value in the array.

If it is found then it should return every position it is found at in the array.

However when I enter a value which I know should be in the array the code will still say that it isn't.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] low256 = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Dingo Ice\Downloads\Low_256.txt");
        Console.WriteLine("Choose a file to use, enter 1: Low, 2: High or 3: Mean");
        int choice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        //Sort Arrays into ascending order
        Array.Sort(low256);
        //Sort Arrays into descending order
        Array.Reverse(low256);

        if (choice == 1)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < low256.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i % 10 == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(low256[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter 1, 2 or 3");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Enter an exact value to search for in the selected array");
        string searchValue = Console.ReadLine();
        int found = 0;
        int counter = 0;
        if (choice == 1)
        {
            foreach (var value in low256)
            {
                if (searchValue == value)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Search value found at position: " + value);
                    found = 1;
                }
                else if (found == 0 && counter >= low256.GetUpperBound(0))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The search value was not found in the selected array");
                }
                counter += 1;
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you change this:

```
if (searchValue == value)
```

To:

```
if (searchValue.ToLower().Trim() == value.ToLower().Trim())
```

And see if this causes a match to be found?

Also, you mentioned that you want every position found to be returned, but in your example this doesn't happen as you only mention via a Console.WriteLine that it is found (but not even on which index). I have changed your log to the Console to include at which index it was found and the index gets added to a list of indexes found.

Does this solve your question?

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string[] low256 = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Dingo Ice\Downloads\Low_256.txt");
        Console.WriteLine("Choose a file to use, enter 1: Low, 2: High or 3: Mean");
        int choice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        //Sort Arrays into ascending order
        Array.Sort(low256);
        //Sort Arrays into descending order
        Array.Reverse(low256);

        if (choice == 1)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < low256.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i % 10 == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(low256[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter 1, 2 or 3");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Enter an exact value to search for in the selected array");
        string searchValue = Console.ReadLine();

        searchValue = searchValue.ToLower().Trim();
        List<int> indexes = new List<int>();

        if (choice == 1)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < low256.Length; i++)
            {
                string value = low256[i].ToLower().Trim();
                if (searchValue == value)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Search value '{value}' found at position: '{i}'.");
                    indexes.Add(i);
                }
            }

            if (indexes.Count == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The search value was not found in the selected array");
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with *LINQ* by *projecting* your *array* into a `ValueTuple`  with `Select`, using `Where` to *filter*, then *selecting* the `index`.

<sub>***Note*** : The [`string.Compare`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.compare?view=netframework-4.7.2) method just gives you the option on how you want to compare the strings, remove or change the option to taste</sub>

```
var ary1 = new string[] { "asd", "sdf", "sdf", "sgfdfg", "dsf", "asd" };

var someValue = "asd";

var indices = ary1.Select((value, index) => (value, index)) // convert to value index tuple
    .Where(pair => string.Compare(pair.value, someValue,CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, CompareOptions.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
    .Select(pair => pair.index);

foreach(var index in indices)
   Console.WriteLine(index);
```

**Output**

```
0
5
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for `Array.IndexOf` method.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] names = { "Mathew", "Mark", "Luke", "John" };
        int index = Array.IndexOf(names, "Luke");
        Debug.Print(index.ToString());
        //Prints 2
    }
```